# Round minutes to only two decimals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rounding

I am making a countdown in React by parsing a string date from state and calculating the remaining minutes to that date and showing the days,  hours that are left, here is my state:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            deadline: 'August 05, 2018'

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="App-title">Offer Expires: {this.state.deadline}</div>
               <Clock
               deadline = {this.state.deadline}
               />

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

and here is my method that calculates the days,minutes,hours:

```
getTimeUntil(deadline) {
    const time = Date.parse(deadline) - Date.parse(new Date());
    const seconds = Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 1000 * 60);
    const hours = Math.floor((time / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    const days = Math.floor(time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    this.setState({ days, hours, minutes, seconds });
  }
```

The problem is that it returns the minutes in the following format in milliseconds:

Days:5 Hours:11 Minutes:28467780 Seconds:54

And I want to round them to two decimals like:

Days:5 Hours:11 Minutes:28 Seconds:54

I have tried to add the `minutes.toFixed(2)` and `minutes.toPrecision(2)`
but it did not round them, how can I do that?

Comment: You need to start at days and work  your way down with the remaining time

Comment: `Date.parse(new Date())` == `Date.now()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just your minutes calculation that's off. It should be something along the lines of

```
const minutes = Math.floor(time / (1000 * 60) % 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing the first two digits seems wrong to me. You should calculate the minutes using `%`, just like you did with hours and seconds.

`const minutes = Math.floor((time / 1000 * 60) % 60);`